# How to make initrd of Ubuntu 16.04 mount /home automatically in addition to /?

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04, fstab, initramfs

This is a follow-up to a [former question](https://serverfault.com/questions/910173/why-cant-systemd-find-service-files-within-a-btrfs-subvolume-within-a-btrfs-roo) about systemd, BTRFS, `/home` being an individual subvolume and the following restriction of systemd I would like to work around:

> The file system where the linked unit files are located must be accessible when systemd is started (e.g. anything underneath /home or /var is not allowed, **unless those directories are located on the root file system**).

`/home` is mounted by systemd properly, but contains service files which systemd should start during boot already as well and that doesn't work. `/etc/fstab` looks like the following:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0841ef72-e9d4-45ca-af22-a403783859c6 /        btrfs   noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@ 0     1

# /home was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0841ef72-e9d4-45ca-af22-a403783859c6 /home    btrfs   noatime,nodiratime,subvol=@home 0 2
```

As initrd is a [compressed archive with lots of scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18055/174233), in theory it's possible to decompress that (`gzip -dc /.../initrd.gz | cpio -id`), change some scripts and mount `/home` additionally. I already found the following code in a file called `init` which seems to be responsible for mounting `/`. Following those function calls reveals parse logic for `fstab` etc.

```
maybe_break mount
log_begin_msg "Mounting root file system"
# Always load local and nfs (since these might be needed for /etc or
# /usr, irrespective of the boot script used to mount the rootfs).
. /scripts/local
. /scripts/nfs
. /scripts/${BOOT}
parse_numeric ${ROOT}
maybe_break mountroot
mount_top
mount_premount
mountroot
log_end_msg
```

The problem is that I don't want to build a new initrd for each and every kernel update of Ubuntu of course.

So besides customizing the scripts manually, is there some other way to get initrd to mount additional file systems like `/home`? Something like kernel parameters provided during startup, maybe some hooks one is able to trigger using special files in `/` or such?

I found the following to be of interest:

```
if read_fstab_entry /usr; then
        log_begin_msg "Mounting /usr file system"
        mountfs /usr
        log_end_msg
fi
```

If I understand correctly, this recognizes additional mount points like `/usr` already. But I couldn't find something like that for `/home`.

Comment: Uh, typically once your root filesystem is mounted `/etc/fstab` will have become available and will used to mount all your other file-systems so you won't have to add anything to your initrd image.

Comment: @HBruijn The problem is that systemd is mounting /home(?) and can't find service files I have there before that(!). I would like to workaround that using initrd and changed my question to make that more clear.

Comment: The bigger question is: why do you have services in `/home` in the first place?

Comment: Then [fix your service files](https://serverfault.com/a/910280/37681) rather than messing about in your initrd.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Because `/home` contains various custom customer software and services. I had a look at user configs for systemd in the meantime, but have some trouble getting those executed automatically. But at least there status is correct.

Comment: Those can run as user services, rather than system services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing extra stuff in the initrd is as simple as writing a shell script (busybox shell to be precise), since initramfs-tools supports hooks/plugins.

In your case, create a script in `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-bottom/mount-home` which could look like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PREREQ=""
prereqs()
{
   echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
   prereqs
   exit 0
   ;;
esac

# Mount /home
mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/1234567890 ${rootmnt}/home
```

Note: `local-bottom` is run after the rootfs has been mounted. The target rootfs is assembled in `${rootmnt}`.

Then you can `update-initramfs` to update your initrd. Every kernel package update will then contain your custom script.

For more documentation, look into the man page of [initramfs-tools.8](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html).